# Replacing widget element with a newly constructed DOM structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, widget

```
<script>
(function( $ ) {

    $.widget( "my.dropbox", {
        errorText: function(text) {
            $(this.element).next().html(text);
        },

        _create: function() {
             var id = $(this.element).attr("id");
             var customDropbox = $(
                "<div class='form-group'>"+
                   "<label for='"+id+"'>"+getLabelFor(id)+"</label>"+
                   "<select id='"+id+"'></select>"+
                   "<div class='errors'></div>"+
                "</div>"
             );
             customDropbox.attr("id", id);

             $(this.element).replaceWith(customDropbox); // This removes original element from DOM

             populateOptions(id);
        },


    });

}( jQuery ));

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#field1").dropbox(); //blank input field turns into a select with a label, populated options e.t.c..
    $("#button1").on("click", function(){
        $("#field1").dropbox("errorText", "This is a validation error message"); //throws an error saying dropbox is not initialized 
    });
});
</script>
<html>
     <body>
         <input id="field1" />
         <button id="button1">Press me</button>
     </body>
</html>
```

So I want a widget with public methods that will replace the original element with all the widget data associated with it. The problem with the above code is that the `<select..>` element is just a DOM element and if you call `.dropbox(..)` on it, it will say the widget is not initialized. Is there a way to make the select element into the widget object with the .errorText() method? All widget examples online add stuff around the original element but never replace it. As for the bigger picture, I'm trying to make a generic tool to configure forms dynamically. It's going to be all `<input id="...">` in html but then javascript will query a database, get configuration for the field and turn it into a `dropbox`, `checkbox` or, say, a `date picker` with all the `labels`, `validation`, and other bells and whistles.

Comment: You say your widget has public methods `.show()` and `.hide()`.  What object are those methods on?  I think we need to see your jQuery widget code to better understand what your situation is and what you're asking.

Comment: The widget is huge I don't think I can post it here but you're absolutely right, what object are those methods on? The problem is, I probably don't understand widgets 100%. What happens now is the widget factory adds .input() method to $, when I call it on a DOM element ._create() gets called, it creates new DOM elements and replaces this.element with them. But what is left after it exits? The DOM was modified and the element on which .input() was originally called is removed and replaced with new DOM elements. So how to turn them into "the widget"?

Comment: Consulting the documentation for your widget library and looking at coding examples is probably in order.  Not much I can do to help without seeing the doc/code for the widget library.

Comment: Rewritten the question with basic code for the widget, please give it one more chance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is more than one issue with your widget code. I'll try to summarize them:

**1. Copy the data**

You're not copying the `data` to the newly created `customDropbox`, so before

```
this.element.replaceWith(customDropbox);
```

you should copy the `data`:

```
customDropbox.data(this.element.data());
```

Now the widget will remember that it was initialized.

**2. this.element is gone**

After

```
this.element.replaceWith(customDropbox);
```

you should update `this.element` so that it points to the newly created `customDropbox`:

```
this.element = customDropbox;
```

**3. errorText message takes wrong element**

Since the widgets element (`this.element`) is now pointing to the `<div class='form-group'></div>` element, the `errorText` function must be slightly modified to:

```
this.element.find(".errors").html(text);
```

**4. id should be unique**

Now, both the wrapper `<div>` and the `<select>` have the same id, which is not allowed in HTML so remove the one on the `<select>` tag. Luckily, `<label>` can work without the `for` attribute, just write it like this:

```
<label>labelForId <select></select></label>
```

Then to get the `<select>`-element, use `this.element.find("select")` in the widget.

**Side note**

```
`this.element` is already a jQuery element, so no need for the additional `$()` wrapping.
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqYQH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(){
   $("#field1").input({....});
}

function hide(){
    $("#field1").input("hide");
}

<button onclick="show()">show</button>
<button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
```

Comment: This is not what I was asking at all.

Answer (score -1):

i think to replace the origin element which initial dropbox()  is not a good solution,

because this will force you to rely on the implemention details of jQuery ui factory,

it is easy to make a mistake or introduce bugs, sometimes harder for other people to understand your code

if jquery ui factory change the implemention in the future, you have to modify all your code to make it work

(sorry for my limit understand of jquery ui)

i think we can put the `<input/>` into a container and initial dropbox() on the container which inturn

replace `<input/>` with `<select>` `datepicker` ..etc.. we can build modules easily by doing so:

```
<form>
  <div class="dropbox"><label for="someID">aaaaaa</label><input id="someID"/></div>
  <div class="datepicker"></div>
  <div class="othermodule"></div>
</form>
```

js:

```
$(".dropbox").dropbox(); // init dropbox you defined 
$(".datepicker").datepicker(); // ...
$(".othermodule").othermodule(); // ...

$(".dropbox").dropbox("errorText", "error"); // invoke it smoothly
```

here is a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4A3D/

@Wouter Huysentruit's answer provides a list of good suggestion for me

```
<form>
  <div class="dropbox">
      <label for="someID">aaaaaa</label>
      <input id="someID"/>
  </div>
  <div class="datepicker"></div>
  <div class="othermodule"></div>
</form>
<button id="button1">Press me</button>



  <script>
  (function ($){
     $.widget("my.dropbox", {
        _create: function () {
            var $input = this.element.find("input");
            var sID = $input.attr("id");
            var $select = $("<select>");
            $select.attr("id", sID);
            $input.replaceWith($select);

            this.element.append("<div class='errors'></div>");
        }, // end _create()
        errorText: function (text) {
            this.element.find(".errors").text(text);
        } // end errorText()
    }); 
  }(jQuery));


$(".dropbox").dropbox();
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $(".dropbox").dropbox("errorText", "this is error");
});
  </script>
```

Comment: I do not agree with 'force you to rely on the implemention details of jQuery ui factory', the only part where we need to rely on it is that the variable `this.element` never gets renamed. And this is not going to happen as it is part of the public API. The rest of the code is pure DOM lookup/manipulation.